# how can reduce the resolution of scan image

Tags: matlab, image-scaling

how can reduce the resolution of scan image

Comment: Is there some specific way to scan images in MATLAB, or are you asking how to resize any image in MATLAB? What is the significance of stating that the image is scanned?

Answer (score 5):

If you intend to resize an image,  simply use the Matlab Image Toolbox.

There is a function for this purpose called **imresize**

```
B = imresize(A, scale)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could:

- just downsample it, take every n-th pixel along each row and column in the original image and write it to a new image; choose n to suit your requirements;
- replace every n*n array of pixels by some average of the pixel values in the array; lots of definitions of average to choose from; again, choose n to suit your requirements.